# Listbox returned items not working

Tags: python, tkinter

Using returned items from Listbox in another command isn't being recognised. Get a message saying `"myBuff"` is not a Field Name. Should `myBuff` be returned as a string?  Other times I get this message: `TypeError: selectBuffer() takes exactly 2 arguments (1 given)`

```
import arcpy,sys,os
from Tkinter import*

class Application(Frame):
    def __init__(self, master=None):
        Frame.__init__(self, master)
        self.grid()
        self.createWidgets(master)

    def createWidgets(self,master):
        #add listbox and populate it
        self.bufList = Listbox(master, height=4, width=17, selectmode=SINGLE)
        self.bufList.grid(row=0, column=0, rowspan=4, columnspan=2, sticky='w')
        self.bufList.insert(END, "Select A Buffer")
        for item in ["5m", "10m", "15m"]:
            self.bufList.insert(END, item)

    #add Select Button
    self.selectButton = Button(master, text='1. Select',command=self.selectBuffer)
        self.selectButton.grid(row=0, column=2, sticky='nw')
        self.selectButton.bind("<<ListboxSelect>>", self.selectBuffer)

    #add method for select button
    def selectBuffer(self, event):
        global select
        select = self.bufList.curselection()
        myBuff = self.bufList.get(select[0])  #get value of selected item
        #perform geoprocessing analysis
        mxd = arcpy.mapping.MapDocument("C:/Projects/MyProject.mxd)
        arcpy.Buffer_analysis("C:/Projects/road.shp", "C:/Projects/roadBuffer100.shp","myBuff") 

root = Tk()
app = Application(master=root)
app.mainloop()
```

Comment: You are passing the string "myBuf" instead of the value.

Comment: Always show full error message (traceback)

Answer (score 0):

You use `selectBuffer` two times.

```
command=self.selectBuffer

self.selectButton.bind("<<ListboxSelect>>", self.selectBuffer)
```

One of this lines expects `def selectBuffer(self, event):`,
another expect `def selectBuffer(self):`
so you get error.

Use `None` as default value for `event` to get rid of the problem.

```
def selectBuffer(self, event=None):
```

Comment: I entered event=None and this is the reply I get.  Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Apps\Python27\ArcGIS10.1\lib\lib-tk\Tkinter.py", line 1410, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "H:\MyCourses\GIST8138\Mod8\4_Buttons.py", line 74, in selectBuffer
    "FULL","ROUND","NONE","#")
  File "C:\Apps\ArcGIS\Desktop10.1\arcpy\arcpy\analysis.py", line 686, in Buffer
    raise e
ExecuteError: Failed to execute. Parameters are not valid.
ERROR 000728: Field myBuff does not exist within table
Failed to execute (Buffer).

Comment: Now you have probably problem with `arcpy.Buffer_analysis()` - not with Tkinter. As stark said in comments: 'You are passing the string "myBuf" instead of the value'. Use `myBuf` in place of `"myBuf"`. Add error message in your question - it will be more readable.